# cocos2d CCScene background orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5

I'm trying to add a background image for my scene using the following code:

```
    CCSprite* background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background-hd.png"];
    background.tag = 1;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [self addChild:background];
```

My apps orientation is landscape and the image's orientation is landscape as well, however I get the image orientated in portrait:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIFnU.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution with Layer which set the scene with orientation...

```
+(CCScene *) scene
 {
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
StartLayer *layer = [StartLayer node];

CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background-hd.png"];
background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

[layer addChild:background z:-1];
[scene addChild: layer];

return scene;
 }
```

See this link for More information [Cocos2d-Scenes-and-Layers](http://ioscreator.com/cocos2d-scenes-and-layers/)....

Hope this helpful to you...

Comment: That works! however the problem was the orientation of the image file it self but thanks anyway!